# How to convert an iterative str.replace() with str.translate()? - python

Tags: python, string, replace, translate, punctuation

The aim of my task is to add spaces before and after punctuation. Currently i've been using an iterative `str.replace()` to replace each punctuation `p` with `" "+p+" "`. **How do i achieve the same output with `str.translate()` where i can just pass in two list or a dictionary**:

```
inlist = string.punctuation
outlist = [" "+p+" " for p in string.punctuation]
inoutdict = {p:" "+p+" " for p in string.punctuation}
```

Lets assume that all the punctuations i have are in `string.punctuation`. Currently, i'm doing it as such:

```
from string import punctuation as punct
def punct_tokenize(text):
  for ch in text:
    if ch in deupunct:
      text = text.replace(ch, " "+ch+" ")
  return " ".join(text.split())

sent = "This's a foo-bar sentences with many, many punctuation."
print punct_tokenize(sent)
```

**Also this iterative `str.replace()` is taking too long, will `str.translate()` be any faster?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict form of translate only works with unicodes:

```
>>> import string
>>> inoutdict = {ord(p):unicode(" "+p+" ") for p in string.punctuation}
>>> unicode("foo,,,bar!!1").translate(inoutdict)
u'foo ,  ,  , bar !  ! 1'
```

Another option is with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> rx = '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)
>>> re.sub(rx, r" \g<0> ", "foo,,,bar!!1")
'foo ,  ,  , bar !  ! 1'
```

As usual, show us a bigger picture to get better answers, e.g. why are you doing that? where does the input come from?, etc...

Comment: what does `\g<0>` mean?

Comment: @alvas: it's a fancy (but only) way to reference the "group zero" - the whole substring found.

Comment: thanks both solution, translate and regex solves the problem of adding spaces before and after punctuation in sentences. i had the `" ".join(spaced_punct_text.split())` to resolve the multiple whitespace output =)

Comment: both solution works a lot faster than the iterative `str.replace()` too =)